# Qual è il significato di "rubare al passo"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> L'uomo era pregiudicato, ladro di pecore nell'immediato dopoguerra e ora, a quanto si sapeva, soltanto mediatore di prestiti a usura: faceva il *confidente* un po' per vocazione un po' illudendosi di avere così privilegio di impunità nel mestiere che faceva; un mestiere che, in confronto a quello di rubare a mano armata, considerava onesto e giudizioso, da padre di famiglia. L'**aver rubato al passo** diceva errore di gioventù: che senza una lira di capitale, scorrendogli tra le mani il denaro degli altri, riusciva ora a campare tre figli e la moglie; e denaro metteva da parte per impiegarlo domani in un piccolo commercio, mettersi dietro un banco di bottega a misurare tessuti era il sogno di tutta la sua vita.

Ho cercato nella voce "passo" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato parecchi riferimenti all'espressione "al passo", ma nulla sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "rubare al passo" nel brano precedente?

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di "passo di montagna" (ovvero del punto di passaggio tra due valli)? In senso più generico, lo interpreterei con il fatto che l'uomo in questione rapinava le persone per strada, magari lungo strade in campagna, appostandosi in passaggi obbligati. È solo una supposizione, però.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rubare al passo** significa mettersi in agguato per derubare qualcuno al passaggio, tendere un'imboscata per rapinare i viandanti.

Grazie al suggerimento di @Gio, secondo il [Nuovo vocabolario Siciliano-Italiano](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=jtFFAAAAcAAJ&q=%22passu.%20s.%20m.%22#v=snippet&q=%22passu.%20s.%20m.%22&f=false) da Antonio Traina, alla voce "passu" si trova la seguente definizione:

> Luogo dove i ladri si mettono a rubare: *agguato, vàlico*; *passo* in riguardo a coloro che passano di quivi. Onde *teniri passu*, rubar per le strade, star al varco, appostarsi. (*Villani* ha: *misono un agguato al valico della pieve*). E *tener il passo*, pigliando *tenere* nel senso di occupare, impedire, potrebbe anco spiegar la nostra frase. || *Jittarisi o mittirisi a lu passu*, rubare i passeggieri per le strade: *gettarsi* o *andar* о *mettersi alla strada*. || *Tinituri di passu*, chi ruba così: *stradajuolo, assassin da strada*.

Si tratterebbe quindi di un’espressione di origine regionale.

Comment: Questa risposta sarebbe più convincente se portasse delle fonti e degli esempi preesistenti.

Comment: Grazie alla sparita risposta di @Gio ho scoperto questa fonte: [Nuovo vocabolario Siciliano-Italiano da Antonio Traina](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=jtFFAAAAcAAJ&q=%22passu.+s.+m.%22#v=snippet&q=%22passu.%20s.%20m.%22&f=false).

Comment: Alla voce "passu" di questo dizionario si trova quello che segue.

Comment: Luogo dove i ladri si mettono a rubare: *agguato, vàlico*; *passo* in riguardo a coloro che passano di quivi. Onde *teniri passu*, rubar per le strade, star al varco, appostarsi. (*Villani* ha: *misono un agguato al valico della pieve*). E *tener il passo*, pigliando *tenere* nel senso di occupare, impedire, potrebbe anco spiegar la nostra frase. || *Jittarisi o mittirisi a lu passu*, rubare i passeggieri per le strade: *gettarsi* o *andar* о *mettersi alla strada*. || *Tinituri di passu*, chi ruba così: *stradajuolo, assassin da strada*.

Comment: Quindi, a quanto pare, si tratterebbe di un'espressione di origine regionale.

Comment: Forse si potrebbe aggiungere questa fonte alla tua risposta.

Comment: @Charo. Aggiunta fonte. Grazie